# Use debounce and async validation only at one field with Formik and yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, asynchronous, yup, debouncing

I'm working with a registration form for my application and, to put you in context, I have the following features/functionality enabled:

- I am using Formik + Yup for validation.
- I am using asynchronous validation to check if emails exist in my bbdd.
- I use loadash/debounce to validate the email within .5s of stop writing.

These are my validationSchema

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  nombre: Yup.string().restOfRules(),
  apellidos: Yup.string().restOfRules(),
  email: Yup.string().restOfRules()
    .test(
      'Email duplicado',
      'Este email ya está en uso.',
      async (value) =>
        new Promise((resolve) => validateEmail(value || '', resolve))
    ),
  });
```

and my email validator function with debounce:

```
const validateEmail = debounce(
  async (value: string, resolve: (val: boolean) => void) => {
    let error = '';

    const res: any = await checkIfEmailExists({ email: value });

    if (res?.data?.exists !== false)
        error = 'Este email ya está en uso.';

    return resolve(error === '');
  },
  500
);
```

Because of all this I run into the following problems:

**1. All fields take .5s to validate, not just the email**.
In this step of the form, my users enter their email, first name and last name, and the problem is that I need the validation of the first name and last name **to be instantaneous**.

As formik validates all the fields at the same time, it takes .5s to validate also the email, so the interface shows that the name is correct moments after typing it.

**2. The asynchronous validation is executed even when I don't type in the email field**.
As I commented in the previous step, since formik validates all the fields at the same time, every time I type the first and last name, it executes a request to my server to validate the email, which I would like to avoid.

I know that the continuous validation of all the fields by Formik is something intentional by the creator of the library himself, so I understand that my second problem is something that can't be avoided at all, but I do worry about the first thing....

So: **Is there any way to specify Formik/Yup to execute the validation of a field only when its value is changing (and, of course, before submitting the form)?**.

Thanks in advance!